# ArcGISOnline request fails for more than 2 outfields with .Net proxy. But working in browser

Tags: c#, proxy, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying load ArcGIS FeatureService with ArcGIS JavaScript. As this featureservice is secure service so I have enabled proxy in ArcGIS JavaScript. The main Problem is **Service request fails while request goes with proxy**. When I checked in Event viewer I see error **The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057. at authproxy.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in**. Anyone have Idea about this?

Comment: Does it work without the proxy (i.e., you have to type in username/password)?
Are you using the resource-proxy from https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy ?

Comment: Yes, I am using resource proxy with clientID and clientSecret. My issue was fixed after using latest version of proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you are accessing the token service via a cross-domain request and both the browser and web server support CORS the ArcGIS API for JavaScript can make a request from an HTTP page to the token service over HTTPS. If CORS support is not available you will need to setup and use a proxy page. The proxy page will then communicate with the token service via HTTPS. In the case of Internet Explorer the entire application needs to be accessed via HTTPS.

Once you have configured the proxy with the application, test the application to ensure that requests are processed correctly. The application should function as it did before the proxy was implemented. If not, you may need to troubleshoot the proxy.

***The following troubleshooting tips may help you find and fix the problem:***

1. If your application environment supports debugging mode, you may be able to set breakpoint in the proxy and detect whether it is operating correctly.
2. Set the ProxyConfig mustMatch attribute to false to proxy all requests. If the application works when this value is set to false then you may not have listed your service in the serverUrls section or you may have a typo in the serverUrl. Don't forget to set this attribute back to true when you have finished troubleshooting the proxy.
3. Enable logging for the proxy. Once enabled messages are written to the log that may be useful when troubleshooting the issue.
4. Make sure you've specified the correct location for your proxy in your application code. You can use browser developer tools to determine if the proxy is located. To do this activate your browser debugging tools then examine the network reqeusts and look for requests that POST to the proxy. If you see a 404 error this means that the proxy was not found. Inspect the request properties to view the path where the application is looking for the proxy.

**Source1-** https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html

**Source2-** https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_secureservices.html

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Answer (score 0):

In Proxy.ashx file just changed

```
response.Flush(); 
response.End();
```

to

```
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

and it started working properly. This changes also available in proxy.ashx file in latest version of resource proxy.